# JS: count how many specific weekdays for each month between two dates

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

So I'm trying to return the number of Thursdays for each month between two dates...

I can count the number of Thursdays between an entire range, but could you help me separate that and return it in a multidimensional array, maybe?

[[month, number_of_Thursdays],
[month, number_of_Thursdays],
[month, number_of_Thursdays],
etc.]

```js
var startDate = new Date('2021/8/16');
var endDate = new Date('2022/3/15');

function countThursdays( days, d0, d1 ) {
  var ndays = 1 + Math.round((d1-d0)/(24*3600*1000));
  var sum = function(a,b) {
    return a + Math.floor( (ndays+(d0.getDay()+6-b) % 7 ) / 7 ); };
  return days.reduce(sum,0);
}

console.log(countThursdays([3],new Date(startDate),new Date(endDate))+" Thursdays");
```

Thank you!

Comment: I can't understand what is your first parameter `days` ?

Comment: What kind of separation do you want?

Comment: @Ludal days is the day number in the week. Thursday = day #3.

Comment: @DhanaD. I would like to be able to return a multidimensional array that lists the 7 months between the two dates in my example, and the number of Thursdays in each of those seven months.

Comment: Can you please write the example desired output of that 2 dates you used in the code in your question?

Comment: How would you do if there are 2 times the same month ? (in 2 different years) For instance, January 2021, and January 2022 ? You may want a result like : `[{year: 2022, month: 1, days: 4}]` isn't it ? (which would mean : there are 4 thursdays in Januar 2022)

Comment: @Ludal true! You're absolutely right!